# How to configure Log4Net to log unhandled exceptions

Tags: log4net

I would like to be able to log unhandled exceptions via configuring log4net.
Is that possible to achieve by only making changes to the config file? if yes, how to do that?
Otherwise if it's not possible, what should I implement in the code to make this happen?

Comment: Different types of apps have different ways of setting up an unhandled exception handler, which you can then use to log the exception to log4net

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with only configuration, you need log the actual exception somewhere. So you need to catch the 'uncatched' exception and them log it.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   // Add the event handler for handling UI thread exceptions to the event.
    Application.ThreadException += new     
  ThreadExceptionEventHandler(ErrorHandlerForm.Form1_UIThreadException);

  // Set the unhandled exception mode to force all Windows Forms errors
  // to go through our handler.
  Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

  // Add the event handler for handling non-UI thread exceptions to the event. 
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new       
  UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
}
```

In the handlers you can log to log4net. After that you can switch them on and off with configuration.

However there are some cases that the exception is not catched. For example when there is a failfast called.